# Predicting a metric variable from a pool of binary independent variables

Tags: regression, prediction, binary-data, structural-equation-modeling

i would like to predict a metric variable (liking) by using a lot of binary variables (about 30). 
What i have done so far: stepwise regression with all the 30 binary variables as independent variables. Doesn't work to great + some of the binarys might be correlating.

Same approach with a SEM-Model. 
I've tryed the direct prediction (arrows pointing from all my binary to the metric liking-variable) and i've tryed an approach with latend variables (with the latent variables driving liking and the binary grouped to the latent variables by a previous cluster-analysis).
The latent variables model has a better fit but still far away from beeing good :(

Is there anything else i can try? 
I want to finde out which of the 30 binary variables are important for liking and how good they predict my liking-scores.

I've heard about CoreEx. Could it help me here?

thx for all your help!

sorry if i double-post my question just by clicking on post. I think the first try didn't work

Comment: Your regression should give you P values for significance.  Also, it's somewhat up to you to choose what variables to include in the regression.

Comment: Is your response variable discrete (liking score = 1 to 10)  or binary (liking = yes or no)?

Comment: I've justed droped in all the 30 variables and did a stepwise regression. 
After that i did the regression again with only the variables left after the stepwise regression. 
My problem is that i get rather poor r-square (0.2) so my overall-prediction isn't very great i would say?

Same thing whit the SEM-Model. Nearly same significant variables as in the regression, but the overall fit is just bad (cmin/df around 14, rmsea around 0,2). It helps to correlate some of the predictors but still the fit is not good. 

My response variable is discrete (1 to 100)

Comment: Poor r-squared can mean a few things.  One of them is that your predictors don't account for the variation in your response.  However, including variables that have no effect on the response can actually hurt your model. Unfortunately there is no easy answer to "what is the correct model for my data"